# Importing from Excel

Tags: import, excel

I'm trying to import a matrix from Excel to Mathematica. My code is:

```
Import["desktop/stproj.xls", "xls", data, 1]
```

The output is some weird stuff about population counts and not at all related to what's in the excel file. Can anyone help me with importing this?

Comment: Marty Cohen's answer below is sage advice--I do the same when I'm trying to import data from a spreadsheet. If that's not an option, then you should probably make your spreadsheet accessible to the SE community.

One thing I'll mention is that your import command should start with a capital letter (as do all built-in Mathematica functions).

Comment: @David, I think `=` in the original question is important in relation to the "weird stuff about population counts...` OP is puzzled about.

Comment: @R.M my comment about the previous edit was unintentionally directed to the David Skulsky. It was intended for David, but I could not figure out how to ping David. I think editing out `=` in the original version destroys the whole question.

Answer (score 8):

With syntax errors fixed:

```
  Import[" appropriate path /Desktop/stproj.xls", "xls", "Data", 1]
```

should import the file.

Regarding `population counts` you are getting, the `=` sign at the beginning of an input cell invokes Wolfram Alpha query which allows free-form input (hence you get no syntax error warnings). Interestingly, Wolfram Alpha interprets the query *somehow* and returns:

[image]

If you click the red `+` button on the top right to get the full results, you see why W|A returns with this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to import Excel data, I first save the Excel file as a csv file with either commas or tabs as the separators. The result is a pure text file that can be readily imported and manipulated.

Comment: Mathematica imports both .xls and .xlsx files so this is not necessary.

Comment: Importing from a csv file is faster than other formats in general.